# What do "DESCENDANTS" and "0, LEAVES" mean?

Tags: mdx

I have the following MDX query:

```
select {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} on axis(0), 
DESCENDANTS({[Customer].[Education].[All Customers].[Bachelors],
             [Customer].[Education].[All Customers].[Graduate Degree]},0,LEAVES) on axis(1) ,
DESCENDANTS({[Geography].[Country].[All Geographies].[Australia],
         [Geography].[Country].[All Geographies].[Canada],
         [Geography].[Country].[All Geographies].[France]},0,LEAVES) on axis(2) 
from [Adventure Works]
```

What do `DESCENDANTS` and `0, LEAVES` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds a strange (generated?) request; it means to return the descendants of the members (specified as the first parameter) in the level of those members. I guess this is equivalent to 0, SELF in that case and therefore equivalent of the members passed as parameter:

```
{
 [Geography].[Country].[All Geographies].[Australia],
 [Geography].[Country].[All Geographies].[Canada],
 [Geography].[Country].[All Geographies].[France]
}
```